# Django SAML logout failing

Tags: django, single-sign-on, saml

In my Django project I use python3-saml to login with SSO. The login works like expected  but the logout is failing with an error message 'No hostname defined'. I really don't know how to solve this as the only parameter passed to logout is the request and request is missing 'http_host' and 'server_name', read [here](https://pythonhosted.org/python-saml/library/_modules/saml2/utils.html).

My logout part looks like following:

```
    def get(self, request, pkuser=None):

        try:
            get_user_model().objects.get(pk=pkuser)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('HomePage')

        logger = logging.getLogger('iam')
        logger.info('IAM logout')

        auth = OneLogin_Saml2_Auth(request, custom_base_path=settings.SAML_FOLDER)

        logger.info('account logout')
        # OneLogin_Saml2_Utils.delete_local_session()

        try:
            auth.logout(
                name_id=request.session['samlNameId'],
                session_index=request.session['samlSessionIndex'],
                nq=request.session['samlNameIdNameQualifier'],
                name_id_format=request.session['samlNameIdFormat'],
                spnq=request.session['samlNameIdSPNameQualifier']
            )
            logger.info('account logout success')
            OneLogin_Saml2_Utils.delete_local_session()
            logger.info('account logout: deleted local session')
        except Exception as e:
            logger.info('account logout failed: {}'.format(str(e)))
           

        logout(request)

        return redirect('HomePage')
```

Maybe I'm using the wrong package...? Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because the `logout` method is missing `http_host` and `server_name`.

To fix this issue modify the request object to include the `http_host` and `server_name` attributes before calling the logout method.

```
def get(self, request, pkuser=None):
    try:
        get_user_model().objects.get(pk=pkuser)
    except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('HomePage')

    logger = logging.getLogger('iam')
    logger.info('IAM logout')

    auth = OneLogin_Saml2_Auth(request, custom_base_path=settings.SAML_FOLDER)

    logger.info('account logout')

    request.http_host = 'your_http_host'
    request.server_name = 'your_server_name'

    try:
        auth.logout(
            name_id=request.session['samlNameId'],
            session_index=request.session['samlSessionIndex'],
            nq=request.session['samlNameIdNameQualifier'],
            name_id_format=request.session['samlNameIdFormat'],
            spnq=request.session['samlNameIdSPNameQualifier']
        )
        logger.info('account logout success')
        OneLogin_Saml2_Utils.delete_local_session()
        logger.info('account logout: deleted local session')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info('account logout failed: {}'.format(str(e)))

    logout(request)

    return redirect('HomePage')
```

Comment: unfortunately this is also not working

Comment: @cwhisperer Do you get any error output?

Answer (score 1):

In the handler for your ACS URL you will also be creating an object from OneLogin_Saml2_Auth(), which theoretically is working. Check if the setup for the request to that is different to the setup here.

One thing that stands out between this and my code is that my one has a line prior to the constructor `request_annotated = saml2_prepare_request(request)` (all the names in this line will likely be different for you other than `request`, but the format would remain the same) where you are passing `request_annotated` to the `OneLogin_Saml2_Auth` constructor rather than `request`. If so, duplicate that line. The library is expecting that there are some specific things annotated to the request dictionary. The code for this function in my Django is:

```
def saml2_prepare_request(request):
    return {
        'http_host': request.META['HTTP_HOST'],
        'script_name': request.META['PATH_INFO'],
        'server_port': request.META['SERVER_PORT'],
        'get_data': request.GET.copy(),
        'post_data': request.POST.copy()
    }
```